# Alternative to animate.css to fadeInDown?

Tags: jquery, fadein, animate.css

I'm using jScrollPane, and it breaks down when I apply animate.css to the page. So I need a "thing" for fadeInDown. I saw that jQuery has its own fadeIn function, but I need it to be faded in with coming down. Do you know any alternatives? It would be awesome if its cross-browser.

edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the fadeInDown will be used when the page loads, not by a click or any other behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$(elem1).click(function(){
   elemToFade = $(elem2);
   elemToFade.animate({'opacity':'0', 'top':'50px'}, 1000);
});
```

#### [FIND A SHORT DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zNQSR/)

```
$('.elem').click(function(){
   elemToFade = $(this);
   elemToFade.animate({'opacity':'0', 'top':'50px'}, 1000, function(){
      elemToFade.hide();
    });
});
```

#### [FIND ANOTHER DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zNQSR/1/)

---

Against latest comment:

```
function movenhide(elemToFade){
   elemToFade.animate({'opacity':'0', 'top':'50px'}, 1000, function(){
      elemToFade.hide();
    });
}

$(function(){  // <------on page load
   movenhide($('div'));
});
```

#### [FIND ONLOAD DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zNQSR/3/)

Comment: You can find another fiddle link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#elem').fadeOut();
});
```